# How do I get from the default view to the 3D Editor View?

Tags: python

[image]
How do I get from here:

To Here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+upkey with the mouse cursor in the windows, the same to get out.
Nkey and tkey to pop side panels.

Comment: Thank you Raul. I got the "Transform" on the right but still don't have the "Translate" field on the bottom left. How do I get the "Transform" to come up?

Comment: Click the translate widget (the red green blue arrows)

Comment: As thilbsert said, that last panel is a dynamic panel that changes according to the function you do, if you use the widget (the colored arrows that pop from the center of an object) and you move the object the translate panel will pop, also others like rotate, scale etc, lots of info there.